# Working with Swift Arrays - How to implement an Array of Objects conforming to a protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates, protocols

In Objective-C I am often using the following "design pattern" in my code to "broadcast" the scenes input callbacks:

```
@protocol RPSceneDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)someMethod;
-(void)didTap;
@end

@interface RPScene : SKScene
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<id<RPSceneDelegate>>* delegates;
-(void)addDelegate:(id<RPSceneDelegate>)delegate_;
-(void)removeDelegate:(id<RPSceneDelegate>)delegate_;
@end

@implementation RPScene

#pragma mark - Delegate Handling

-(void)addDelegate:(id<RPSceneDelegate>)delegate_ {

    if ([self.delegates containsObject:delegate_]) return;
    [self.delegates addObject:delegate_];
}

-(void)removeDelegate:(id<RPSceneDelegate>)delegate_ {

    if (![self.delegates containsObject:delegate_]) return;
    [self.delegates removeObject:delegate_];
}

-(void)didTap {

    for (id<RPSceneDelegate> delegate_ in self.delegates) {

        // Just a small example to show what I am doing
        [delegate_ performSelector:@selector(didTap)];
    }
}

@end
```

Last night I tried to convert this to swift using Swift-Arrays (not NSMutableArray) but I ended up totally frustrating when checking:

```
array.contains(theObject)
```

To get a better understanding of Swift it would help me if someone could convert that little piece of code to Swift. So how do I implement that in Swift!?

EDIT: My code in Swift

```
protocol RPSceneDelegate {
    func someMethod()
}

class RPScene: SKScene {

    var delegates = [RPSceneDelegate]()

    func addDelegate(delegate: RPSceneDelegate) {

        if !delegates.contains(delegate) {
            delegates.append(delegate)
        }
    }
}
```

What works fine is:

```
delegates.append(delegate)
```

What gives me an error is:

```
delegates.contains(delegate)
```

The Compiler says:

> Cannot convert value of type 'RPSceneDelegate' to expected argument
>   type '@noescape (RPSceneDelegate) throws -> Bool'

Problem is. I just don't know what that means ... My first idea was that .contains() requires a function, not an instance / object but I have no clue how to implement that...

Comment: show the code you tried and the error / issue you had (with compile message or stack trace)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a helpful error message...

What is means is that in order to check if an array contains something the compiler needs to be able to compare them. At the moment the objects only respond to a simple protocol so the compiler has no idea how to compare them.

Your protocol needs to extend `Equatable`, and depending on exactly what your objects conforming to this protocol are you may need to implement the equality function.